# Derivative of a Vector-Valued Function

Tags: calculus, vectors

I was completing my Webassign earlier and a particular problem came up.

> Find the open interval(s) on which the curve given by the vector-valued function is smooth. (Enter your answer using interval notation.)
>
> $r(t) = 9t^2i + 7t^3j$

The answer turned out to be $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$.

But the issue I have with the problem is the intuition, and thus leading to my question:

**Why can't the derivative of the vector-valued function equal $0$ and be smooth?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473797/conditions-for-a-smooth-parametric-curve). Basically, for parametric curves (and this is parametric — the parameter is $t$), the definition of smooth means that the derivative is continuous and not equal to the zero vector at any point.

Intuitively, if the derivative of a "normal" (non-parametric) function is zero, then that tells us we have a max or min. In a parametric curve, it could mean that the curve reaches a point, stops, and heads sharply off in another direction, creating a three dimensional cusp.

Clearly that doesn't happen here, but the non-zero requirement has still worked its way into the definition.

Comment: Sorry to add to this 5 years later, but someone just upvoted so I saw this: my last line is wrong. It's not clear that this doesn't happen here because it does. There is a cusp when $t=0$.